# Pack Addon or PointerProperty/PropertyGroup with Blend File For Cloud Rendering

Tags: python, add-on, blend-files, custom-attributes, packing

I wrote an addon that takes a 3D-printing GCode file and turns it into a renderable object.

I define a pointer property and then use members of that pointer property to drive the visibility of different types of features.

This is the UI:
[image]

[image]

It works perfectly fine on an instance of Blender with the plugin installed. This is the code:

```py
class Buddy_Props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    ObjectName: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Object Name', description='What to name the imported object collection', default='OBJECT')
    BevelName: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Bevel Name', description='What to name the created bevel profiles', default='bevel')
    FilePath: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='File Path', description="Path of GCode file", subtype="FILE_PATH")
    
    SeamAbberation_Amount: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Seam Abberation Distance', default=0, description='The maximum amount to vary the seams', min=0)
    SeamAbberation_Probability: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Seam Abberation Probability', default=0, description='The probability with which a seam would be picked to be varied.\n0 being none and 1 being all', min=0, max=100)
    WidthOffset: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Width Offset', default=0, description='All the lines widths would be offset by this amount', min=-1, max=1)
    HeightOffset: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Height Offset', default=0, description='All the lines heights would be offset by this amount ', min=-1, max=1)
    ExtruderError_Density: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Extruder Error Density', default=0.1, description='The density of extruder mistakes', min=0.00, max=1.00, step=0.05)
    ExtruderError_Probability: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Extruder Error Probability', default=0, description='The probability with which a point would be picked to be varied.\n0 being none and 1 being all', min=0)

    Gap_fill: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Gap fill', default=True)
    External_perimeter: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='External perimeter', default=True)
    Overhang_perimeter: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Overhang perimeter', default=True)
    Perimeter: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Perimeter', default=True)
    Top_solid_infill: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Top solid infill', default=True)
    Bridge_infill: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Bridge infill', default=True)
    Internal_infill: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Internal infill', default=True)
    Custom: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Custom', default=True)
    Solid_infill: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Solid infill', default=True)
    Skirt_Brim: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Skirt/Brim', default=True)
    Support_material: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Support material', default=True)
    Support_material_interface: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Support material interface', default=True)
    
    ViewportOnly: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Veiwport Only', description="The filters below would only affect the viewport.\nThe features would still appear in the render", default=True)

    End_Point: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='End Point', default=True)
    Extruder_Error: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Extruder Error', default=True)


    SeamDistance: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Seam Distance', default=0.2, description='How far apart should the seams be to get a desired look', min=0)
    LayerIndexTop: bpy.props.IntProperty(name='Layer Index', default=5000, description='The topmost layer to show, every layer after this would be hidden', min=0)

    Status = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Status', description="Processing Status", default="Not Processing")
```

```py
def register():
    print('registered') # just for debug
    for klass in CLASSES:
        bpy.utils.register_class(klass)

    bpy.types.Scene.Buddy_Props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Buddy_Props)
```

The property appears in scene custom attributes of the scene like this:
[image]

This property is used to drive the visibility of the features like this:
[image]

But these drivers fail when I open the blend file in an instance of Blender without the plugin installed. I'm going to use a cloud rendering solution to render my project. How can I work around this? Hopefully with minimal code changes. It's my own plugin so I have full access of course and I have no problem packing a copy of the plugin with the blend file if possible.

This is the same file opened in a Blender instance without the plugin:
[image]

Comment: regular custom props should be accessible with `["Buddy_props"]` instead of directly `Buddy_props`

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Anyhow, I found a workaround. I'm using a service like vast.ai and installing the plugin before rendering.